# Create spiral with mesh line in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to take a line mesh, plug it into a 'set-position' node and use a mathematical equation to shape the line into a spiral?

Comment: I'm working on a tutorial to show the different ways you can shape a mesh, e.g y=mx+c, y=ax^2, sin t, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

of course you can!

here is the node setup:

[image]

Comment: Chris, you are amazing, man!

Comment: thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Thank YOU, sir.