# Custom Spiral with end and start line - Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I want to create a spiral with the start and end points extended, as shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spiral slide with geo nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271084/spiral-slide-with-geo-nodes)

Comment: No, I need also beginning and ending offset lines. also it will be great that spiral function will be made more mathematical from sin and cos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply offset the start point and end point of a spiral along its tangents:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Resolved, but do You know a way to make spiral without Spiral node?

Comment: @MateuszHanula *Spiral without spiral node?* Yes, but I think on this topic you should create a new question.

Comment: @MateuszHanula I have found something for you that might help you further: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253724/create-spiral-with-mesh-line-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: Ok, Thank You for Your Time